# java, swing; simple gui where to create objects

Tags: java, swing

I have written a simple Command-Line programm that disolves car license plates.
like:

- V -> Vienna
- la -> Los Angeles

Now I want to make a simple GUI (its my first gui) for that programm.
here're my classes:

> Dissolver.java // dissolves car plates ; and contains whole logic
>
> DissolverGUI.java // gui for Dissolver

My problem is: where should I create my object of Dissolver in the DissolverGui class?

I hope you are able to understand my problem

Comment: Your plan to separate GUI from logic is a noble one. Consider creating your Dissolver in the main method and passing it into the GUI via either a `setDisolver(Dissolver dissolver)` method or via a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is too broad. It's hard to give an advice without seeing the code. You can try adding a field in `DissolverGui` class referencing `Dissolver` and use it from all methods. Suppose the right place to create it is the `public static void main(String[])` method which will run the whole program.

As a beginner do not bother yourself about the style, just make the program work as you want.